# how to set the selected value tag <select> html from database in php?

Tags: php, html, mysql, html-select

I'm trying to create a drop down menu that will select a value that is stored in the database. here's the code :

```
require 'koneksi.php';
    $sql_select = "SELECT * FROM supplier"; 
    $hasil = mysql_query($sql_select);
    if(!$hasil) {
        echo "data supplier not found ".mysql_error();
    }

    $id = $_GET["id"];
    $hasil2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brg_supplier WHERE id_brg=".$id);
    $data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil2);
    if($hasil2) {
    $supplier = $data['nama_supplier'];
    }


<select name="supplier">
     <option value="">---pilih supplier---</option>
     <?php
        while($baris = mysql_fetch_array($hasil)){
     ?>
     <option value="<?php $baris['nama_supplier'] ?>" <?php if     ($supplier==$baris['nama_supplier']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> > <?php echo  $baris['nama_supplier']; ?> </option>; 
<?php   }?>
</select>
```

the problem is my code creates a dropdown with nothing selected. here's the screenshot : [link](http://postimg.org/image/kh7a5t1ll/)

i've tried all the solutions in the stackoverflow. but the dropdown value still nothing selected. i know that it has to be something simple that i am missing but seriously i cannot figure it out. please anyone help, thanks!

Comment: see if this helps

`<option value="<?php $baris['nama_supplier'] ?>">
<?php if($supplier==$baris['nama_supplier']) { echo 'selected'; } ?>
<?php echo  $baris['nama_supplier']; ?>
</option>`

Comment: you can minify your code like this
`<option value="<?=$baris['nama_supplier']?>" <?=$supplier==$baris['nama_supplier']?selected:''?> > <?=$baris['nama_supplier']?> </option>; `

Comment: `mysql` has been depreciated. One curial error I can see is you've used `$hasil` rather than `$hasil2`.

Comment: please show your all column name of the supplier and brg_supplier table

Comment: @VishalSharma the column of supplier : id_supplier, nama_supplier, alamat, telp. brg_supplier : id_brg, barang, nama_supplier, harga, ket

Comment: @Beneto i need to retrieve different data from $hasil and $hasil2

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem lies in this line:

```
<option value="<?php $baris['nama_supplier'] ?>" <?php if     ($supplier==$baris['nama_supplier']) echo 'selected="selected"'; ?> > <?php echo  $baris['nama_supplier']; ?> </option>;
```

You're missing an echo and it looks funny :/
Try instead:

```
<option <?php $val=$baris['nama_supplier']; echo "value='$val'";  if($supplier==$val) echo "selected='selected'>";echo $val;?> </option>;
```

Comment: thanks anyway. well, it was funny :/ 
i dont know why i cant figure it out that mistake

Answer (score 0):

```
    Try this way..

$sel="select f.*,c.category from final f, category c where f.category_id=c.id and f.id='$id'";
$data=mysql_query($sel);
$res=mysql_fetch_assoc($data);    

     <select name="cat">
                       <?php

                        $sql = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM category");
                        while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)){
                           if($row['id'] ==  $res['category_id']){
                        echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'" selected="selected">'.$row['category'].'</option>';
                           }else{
                       echo '<option value="'.$row['id'].'">'.$row['category'].'</option>';
                           }
                        }
                       ?>
                  </select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this out

```
require 'koneksi.php';
$sql_select = "SELECT * FROM supplier"; 
$hasil = mysql_query($sql_select);
if(!$hasil) {
    echo "data supplier not found ".mysql_error();
}

$id = $_GET["id"];
$hasil2 = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM brg_supplier WHERE id_brg=".$id);
$data = mysql_fetch_array($hasil2);
if(mysql_num_rows($hasil2) > 0) {
$supplier = $data['nama_supplier'];
}


<select name="supplier">
 <option value="">---pilih supplier---</option>
 <?php
    while($baris = mysql_fetch_array($hasil)){
 ?>
 <option value="<?php echo $baris['nama_supplier'] ?>" <?php if      ($supplier==$baris['nama_supplier']) {echo 'selected="selected"';} ?> > <?php echo  $baris['nama_supplier']; ?> </option>; 
<?php   }?>
</select>
```

Comment: thanks, it works. simply i just missing the 'echo'. but i had to remove this code `<option value="">---pilih supplier---</option>` to show selected value.

Comment: @anggimery: if its works then please right my answer as usefull so that its help to other

Answer (score 0):

```
<option value="<?php $baris['nama_supplier'] ?>
```

should be

```
<option value="<?php echo $baris['nama_supplier'] ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I spent some time trying to find the best solution for this, and came up with a tiny little *jQuery* code.

First of all you should be using `PDO` or `mysqli` instead of `mysql`, since it's [deprecated](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/migration55.deprecated.php). Let's assume you've fixed that.

Inside the `<form>` tag, add an `<input type="hidden"/>` so that it can storage your database value, for example:

**HTML**

```
<form>
    <input id="valueFromDatabase" type="hidden" value="<?php echo $stringFromDB ?>"/>
</form>
```

**Note:** in this case, `$stringFromDB` is a variable that holds your query's return from DB.

So now we have the value of our database inside our HTML code. Now we just need to check if any of the options inside the `<select>` tag is equal to this value. We'll be doing it with jQuery:

**jQuery**

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('option').each(function(){
        if (this.value == $('#valueFromDatabase').val()){
            this.setAttribute('selected', 'selected');
        }
    });
});
```

What's happening here? We are telling to jQuery to analyze all the `<option>` tags in the HTML and compare its value with our value from database; if its equal, we add the selected attribute to the equivalent `<option>`.

You can it working [here](http://www.bootply.com/BnbkUN6kA5) (used a calendar example).

Hope that helps!